# How can I tell if a specific ProcessName is running without crashing

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2012

Lets say there is an application with the name exampleService that should be running on Server1. This code works if it is running. However when it's not running, it crashes.

```
$application = Get-Process -ComputerName Server1 -Name "exampleService"
```

I get this crash if the application is not running. Is there a more graceful way of finding out if it's not running (without crashing)

```
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "exampleService". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:16
+ $application = Get-Process -ComputerName Server1 -Name "exampleService"
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Sampler:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Also is it possible to launch the application on the Server if it's not running?

The Server is running Windows Server 2012. The PowerShell commands are being run from a Windows 7 64-bit PC.

Comment: FYI : receiving an error != the same as crashing. A PS script will continue to run in most circumstances even when you encounter an error (with unpredictable results if the next command relies on the output of the previous command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to keep that error from displaying. You can use that in an If statement to launch the application if it isn't running.

--Updated to include launching the remote process

```
If (-NOT (Get-Process -Computername Server1 -name "cmd" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { 
    Write-Host "Launch application"
    $application = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
    $start = ([wmiclass]"\\Server1\Root\CIMV2:win32_process").Create($application)
}
```

Comment: This is real code. I just made up a process name that doesn't exist to ensure that it would force it to display the `"Launch Application"` text. You would replace that text with the actual command (and the real process name to look for) to launch your application.

Comment: I just tested with cmd and it doesn't appear to do anything.. If (-NOT (Get-Process -name "cmd" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    'Launch application'
    $application = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
    $start = {([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($application)}
}

Comment: It works for me (running Windows 7 / PowerShell V4). You should remove the curly braces in your last line as that only creates a sciptblock but does not actually run the code. `$start = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($application)`

Comment: But will it create the process on my computer or the remote computer?

Comment: I updated the example to better meet what you are looking to do which should launch the remote process.

Comment: It didn't work. Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "cmd". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Process -ComputerName Server1 -Name "cmd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cmd:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: Did you ensure that `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is included in the Get-Process call?

Comment: I copied your code. I changed Server1 with the actual server name

Comment: Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "cmd". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Process -ComputerName CAM12STOR1 -Name "cmd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cmd:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
 
Launch application ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| it does actually create a cmd.exe process on the server but no window appears!!!!

Comment: I cannot duplicate your error. I am able to launch cmd.exe without error using the code and am able to go back an locate the process using `Get-Process`. You won't see the window on the remote system when you launch the remote process. You may have to use something like Psexec.exe for that to work.

Comment: Does PSexec need to be on the Server or on the Client running the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `ErrorAction`to `SilentlyContinue` (alias for that is `-ea 0`):

`$application  = Get-Process -ComputerName Server1 -Name "exampleService" -ea 0`

Now you can check `$application` and start the application if its null.

Comment: how do you start the application?

Answer (score 1):

I only wanted my script to continue on one particular Get-Process error, i.e. process not found.  (and I preferred to use a Try/Catch).    But I haven't done much powershell and had trouble locating the specific error.

Once I found I could look at FullyQualifiedErrorId and added the following to a general Catch block I located what I was after.

```
Write-Host ('FullyQualifiedErrorId: ' + $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId);
```

So as a full example which works for my situation:

```
Try {
    $application = Get-Process -Name "exampleService" -ea Stop  #note the -ea Stop is so try catch will fire whatever ErrorAction is configured
} Catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] {
   If ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId) {
     If ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -eq "NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand"){
        Write-Host "Presume not running. That is OK.";   # or you could perform start action here
     }
   }
   else {
     throw #rethrow other processcommandexceptions
   }
} Catch {
    # Log details so we can refine catch block above if needed
    Write-Host ('Exception Name:' + $_.Exception.GetType().fullname); # what to put in the catch's square brackets
    If ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId) {
        Write-Host ('FullyQualifiedErrorId: ' + $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId); #what specific ID to check for
    }
    throw  #rethrow so script stops 
}
```